# Cut string with a specific pattern

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm new to bash scripting, and I would like to cut a string given a specific pattern. For example with the string `/user/patch.403.json` I would like to get and store in a variable `/user` only. How can I do this with one line of code?

Comment: This can be done in many different ways. It would be good if you indicate what is your final goal or, at least, what is the idea underlying: the first block? everything but the last two? ...

Comment: Another example with this pattern `/user/cards/1212/make_default/put.200.json`, I would like to get `/user/cards/1212/make_default`. My goal is to only get the beginning of the string eliminating `/put.200.json` with basic commands like cut or sed.

Comment: Is this about directories or text? If you got a relative path, say `foo.txt`, would you want the empty string or `.`? This looks to me like a case for `dirname`.

Comment: this is a text contained in a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Wintermute says, you can use the `dirname` command:

```
> dirname /user/patch.403.json
/user
> dirname /user/cards/1212/make_default/put.200.json
/user/cards/1212/make_default
> dirname put.200.json
.
```